# Cannot load XML documents on web page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I am trying to load my parse my XML document but the HTML page remains null, is there something that I'm doing wrong.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
<body onLoad="outputXML('content', 'assets/xml/sample.xml', 'assets/xml/sample.xsl');"></body>
```

**script.js**

[Click here to view the code](http://pastebin.com/nC7iqdNZ)

**sample.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hitrecords>
  <record genre="Ska">
    <artist category="group" gender="male">Madness</artist>
    <title>Baggy Trousers</title>
    <length>
      <minutes>3</minutes>
      <seconds>30</seconds>
    </length>
  </record>
</hitrecords>
```

**sample.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="hitrecords/record">
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:value-of select="@genre"/> 
                <xsl:value-of select="artist"/> 
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested your example and it's working with the adjustment to add an element with the `id="content"` to the HTML:

```
<body onLoad="outputXML('content', 'assets/xml/sample.xml', 'assets/xml/sample.xsl');">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

The `function outputXML(location, xml, xsl) { ...}` that is called with `content` as value for the parameter `location` calls the `function processXML (location, xml, xsl) { ... }`.
This function appends the `resultDocument` to an element with an `id` that has the value of `location`:

```
document.getElementById(location).appendChild(resultDocument);
```